# sql select AND if posted OR if not

Tags: php, sql

i am doing a search form and all the fields are optional

so if i did a select statement with AND.... if there is a  field not posted i'll not get any result 
and if i did select statement with OR i'll get an extensive result

```
    $result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM property WHERE 
   (Typ='$_POST[typ]' OR Purpose='$_POST[purpose]' OR City='$_POST[city]' OR a='$_POST[add]')
                  GROUP BY p_num ORDER BY Add_date DESC ");
```

is there a way to to specific the posted fields and do the select statement for them

Comment: generate the statement in code not in sql (unless you wanna use mysql's if statements eeeuuurrrrgggghh) so you'd have either a switch or a series of if statements that build your conditionals and then you create your final sql string at the end and then you run it

Comment: What exactly you want

Comment: Obligatory comment about how one shall not directly put user input into a query.

Comment: Make your question clearer.What exactly your point is ?

Comment: Either you would want multiple search fields to broaden the results or to narrow down the results. Choose OR or AND for this purpose... What is the question really? (You might want to use `LIKE` syntax for your search query) - AND prepare your statements...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure with optional "WHERE" parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697671/stored-procedure-with-optional-where-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the user have given input or not using isset()

Comment: thank you i used if( !empty) instead just to make sure the fields are not submitted with empty value

Answer (score 1):

Before answering, a first remark : you should use prepared statements as doing it like this is highly unsecure.

Now, for the answer, you should do any manipulation/filtering/testing with your `$Post` variables on beforehand, generating your SQL query on the way, and finally using this sql query you built bits by bits to query the database.