# SQL ignore part of WHERE if parameter is null

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that fetches info from a table based on 4 parameters.

I want to get values based on the parameters, but if a parameter is NULL then that parameter isn't checked. So if all 4 parameters is null I would show the entire table.

This is my SP (as you can see, this only works for 1 parameter atm):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
    @Param1 nvarchar(50),
    @Param2 nvarchar(50),
    @Param3 nvarchar(50),
    @Param4 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Param1 IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable WHERE col1 LIKE @Param1+'%'
        END
END
```

Is there some way to do this *without* having a `IF` for every possible combination (15 IFs)?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) would be the usual starting place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedure with optional "WHERE" parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697671/stored-procedure-with-optional-where-parameters)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   col1 LIKE @Param1+'%'
OR      @Param1 IS NULL
```

in this specific case you could have also used

```
SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   col1 LIKE ISNULL(@Param1,'')+'%'
```

But in general you can try something like

```
SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   (condition1 OR @Param1 IS NULL)
AND     (condition2 OR @Param2 IS NULL)
AND     (condition3 OR @Param3 IS NULL)
...
AND     (conditionN OR @ParamN IS NULL)
```

Comment: Beware. The `IS NULL` leads to a full scan table access.

Comment: I got this working, but could not understand how `condition1` gets ignored if `@Param1 IS NULL`. I have the following condition `(m.idAgent = agent OR agent is null)`. It simply returns me all agents if i pass null to `agent` param. That's awesome! Can you please explain this?

Comment: This is a great solution, works really well. Thanks!

Comment: Also important to note - order of expression evaluation is not guaranteed. That is, you can't rely on short-circuiting. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/03/03/dont-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case/

Comment: Hi @AmitChigadani , When you pass NULL to agent parameter, m.idAgent = agent will not be true if the m.idAgent is NULL. i.e. you are checking if NULL=NULL, which is False as Null is not equal to Null. That's when the second part of the expression (agent IS NULL) gets executed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

You can use use `COALESCE()` function in SQL server. You don't need to use `IF- Else` or `CASE` in your statements. Here is how you can use `COALESCE`function.

```
SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable where col1 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param1, ''), col1) and col2 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param2, ''), col2) and col3 = COALESCE(NULLIF(@param3, ''), col3) and col4=
COALESCE(NULLIF(@param4, ''), col4)
```

The `COALESCE` function in SQL returns the first non-NULL expression among its arguments. Here for example if the @param1 is equal to null the function will return col1 which will lead to col1=col1 in the where statement which is like 1=1 meaning the condition will always be true.

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
    @Param1 nvarchar(50),
    @Param2 nvarchar(50),
    @Param3 nvarchar(50),
    @Param4 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Param1 IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable WHERE col1 LIKE @Param1+'%' OR @Param1 is Null
        END
END
```

This should help

regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: This is an easiest solution, but with long scripts i have to code long parts again and again. :(

Comment: What if only this statement from the above solution. :- SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable WHERE (col1 LIKE @Param1+'%' OR @Param1 is Null) and ...

Answer (score 5):

If you mean @param1 is parameter for col1, @param2 is parameter for col2,... etc
You can try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
@Param1 nvarchar(50),
@Param2 nvarchar(50),
@Param3 nvarchar(50),
@Param4 nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
declare @query nvarchar(4000)
SET @query='SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable '+
    (case when ((@Param1 is null) and (@Param2 is null) and (@Param3 is null) and (@Param4 is null))
    then ''
    else
        'where '+
        (case when @Param1 is not null
        then ' col1 like '''+@param1+'%'''+
            (case when @param2 is not null then ' AND ' else '' end)
        else '' end)+
        (case when @Param2 is not null
        then ' col2 like '''+@param2+'%'''+
            (case when @param3 is not null then ' AND ' else '' end)
        else '' end)+
        (case when @Param3 is not null
        then ' col3 like '''+@param3+'%'''+
            (case when @param4 is not null then ' AND ' else '' end)
        else '' end)+
        (case when @Param4 is not null
        then ' col4 like '''+@param4+'%'''
        else '' end)
    end)

exec sp_sqlexec @query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @criteria nvarchar (max)
SELECT       col1,col2,col3
FROM            table1
((col1+col2+col3 like '%'+@criteria+'%')  OR ISNULL(@criteria, '') = '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure
  @Param1 nvarchar(50) **= '',**              //#1
  @Param2 nvarchar(50) **= '',**
  @Param3 nvarchar(50) **= '',**
  @Param4 nvarchar(50) **= ''**
AS
BEGIN
    **SET @Param1 = ISNULL(@Param1, '')**     //#2

    SELECT Id, col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM myTable WHERE col1 LIKE @Param1+'%' 
END
```

1. Give default value(empty string '' ) to your params: If caller skip passing these params you will receive an empty string that will work fine with your like clause *(ex. myProcedure @Param4 = 'some value' // in this case other parameters will be set to empty string('') @param1  )*
2. Set params to '' to save yourself from null parameters(ex. myProcedure Param1 = null, @param2 = null ... // in this case like won't work on the null values and will give you no record against the parameter, to avoid that do an additional check for null value.

Comment: The problem with this is you now have a default value, even if it is empty string or whatever else that you might so desire - if per chance there is a match you get the returned result.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and easier to understand, at least for me.
The `IIF` statement is only available in **SQL Server 2012** and up, you can replace it with a case statement.

```
SELECT Id, col1, col2, ... 
FROM    myTable 
WHERE   condition1 = IIF(col1 IS NULL, col1, @Param1)
AND     condition2 = IIF(col2 IS NULL, col2, @Param2)...
```

Answer (score -4):

Add Condition in where and using `CASE .. WHEN .. THEN..`

TRY TO FOLLOWING WAY.

```
select col1,col2,...colN..from Table 
Where clm1 = CASE WHEN @PARAMETER = 0 THEN **COL1** ELSE **@PARAMETER**
```

ONCE YOU SET SAME COLUMN NAME INTO WHERE CONDITION THEN YOU RETRIEVE ALL DATA FROM TABLE ELSE IF YOU WANT TO PASS AS PARAMETER THEN RETRIEVE BASE ON CONDITION VALUES FROM TABLE.

Comment: This is an unnecessary use of all caps. What is the point? What are you trying to emphasize?