# WHERE clause where some parameters can be null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I am tasked with pulling a count of records that fall within a start time and end time while **possibly** being filtered down by @aircraftId, @instructorId and @reservationId (so it ignores itself in the count). All three parameters are nullable, so they may or may not be passed, so the query will have to filter based on them being there or not. I can do this with dynamic Sql, but I prefer to avoid it, mainly because it's a pain to debug for anyone that has to deal with it later.

Is this possible (I'm guessing it is) in a single query? Or, is this one of those situations where I have to grab set and pare it down with the other parameters if they are present?

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    AVMAN.Reservation
WHERE   ( @aircraftid IS NULL
            OR ( @aircraftid IS NOT NULL
                AND AircraftId = @aircraftid
                )
        )
        OR ( @InstructorId IS NULL
                OR ( @InstructorId IS NOT NULL
                    AND InstructorUserId = @InstructorId
                )
            )
        AND ( ( -- start during the range
                StartTime >= @StartTime
                AND StartTime < @EndTime
                )
                OR ( -- end during the range 
                    EndTime > @StartTime
                    AND EndTime <= @EndTime
                    )
                OR ( -- start before the range and end after it
                    StartTime < @StartTime
                    AND EndTime > @EndTime
                    )
            )
        AND ( @ReservationId IS NULL
                OR ( ReservationId IS NOT NULL
                    AND ReservationId = @ReservationId
                    )
            )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850726/sql-ignore-part-of-where-if-paramter-is-null

Comment: You could simplify:
`@aircraftid IS NULL OR ( @aircraftid IS NOT NULL AND AircraftId = @aircraftid)`
To:
`@aircraftid IS NULL OR AircraftId = @aircraftid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your original SQL you have an OR rather than an AND which will throw off your results.

To tidy up the filters on aircraftId, instructorId and reservationId you can do the following:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    AVMAN.Reservation
WHERE   
    ISNULL( @AircraftId, AircraftId ) = AircraftId 
    AND
    ISNULL( @InstructorId, InstructorId ) = InstructorId 
    AND
    ISNULL( @ReservationId, ReservationId ) = ReservationId 
    AND 
    ( ( -- start during the range
            StartTime >= @StartTime
            AND StartTime < @EndTime
            )
            OR ( -- end during the range 
                EndTime > @StartTime
                AND EndTime <= @EndTime
                )
            OR ( -- start before the range and end after it
                StartTime < @StartTime
                AND EndTime > @EndTime
                )
        )
```

The ISNULL basically compares AircraftId to @AircraftId when that's not null, and compares with AircraftId (which will obviously always be the same) when @AircraftId is null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try to use CASE in WHERE clause like this

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    AVMAN.Reservation
WHERE CASE
        WHEN @aircraftid IS NULL THEN 1 
        WHEN @aircraftid IS NOT NULL AND  AircraftId = @aircraftid THEN 1 
     END = 1 
     AND 
     CASE 
        WHEN @InstructorId IS NULL  THEN 1
        WHEN @InstructorId IS NOT NULL AND InstructorUserId = @InstructorId THEN 1
     END = 1
     AND ( ( -- start during the range
                StartTime >= @StartTime
                AND StartTime < @EndTime
                )
                OR ( -- end during the range 
                    EndTime > @StartTime
                    AND EndTime <= @EndTime
                    )
                OR ( -- start before the range and end after it
                    StartTime < @StartTime
                    AND EndTime > @EndTime
                    )
            )
        AND 
         CASE 
            WHEN @ReservationId IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN ReservationId IS NOT NULL AND ReservationId = @ReservationId THEN 1
         END = 1
```