# SQL prompt where the user only enters one condition

Tags: sql

I have what may be a dumb question for SQL. My team currently uses some queries to find information relevant to their work. The query we have set up prompts them to enter in conditions. The query looks like this:

```
Select something

From sometable

where '{{condition1}}'
And '{{condition2}}'
```

There are two fields below the query where the user enters in condition1 and condition2 then runs the query. I am wondering if there is a way to enter either condition1 or condition2, but not both if the user only knows one of the conditions.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850726/sql-ignore-part-of-where-if-paramter-is-null

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question since it is pretty vague, however, using parameters in your sql statement, if you always pass in two values make one or both nullable and account for the lack of value.

```
Select something
From sometable
where 
    ((Condition1 IS NULL)OR(Condition1=SomeValue))
    AND
    ((Condition2 IS NULL)OR(Condition2=SomeValue2))
```