# SQL ignore null array with WHERE IN UNNEST clause

Tags: python, sql, arrays, postgresql, psycopg2

I was using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850726/sql-ignore-part-of-where-if-parameter-is-null) until I got to work with arrays.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM listening_history WHERE 
(composition_id IN (SELECT UNNEST(%(arr)s)) OR %(arr)s is NULL) 
limit 50
```

and code

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
# arr = None
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM listening_history WHERE '
               '(composition_id IN (SELECT UNNEST(%(arr)s)) OR %(arr)s is NULL) '
               'limit 50',
               {'arr': arr})
```

This works just fine when array is not null, but unlike in general solution case I have to use unnest first before use my parameter. Because of this I'm getting error that it is not possible to do this

```
UNNEST(NULL)
```

How can I ignore null array without using user-defined functions if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm a really ashamed of myself because when I was writing this question I found solution myself.

You can just do it like this

```
SELECT * FROM listening_history WHERE 
(composition_id = ANY(%(arr)s) OR %(arr)s is NULL) 
limit 50
```

I am really ashamed of myself

Comment: You should NOT be ashamed. This means you had a problem and posted the question. Ok, that is why SO exists. It also means you did not just wait for someone to tell you how, you persisted and found an answer. I would classify that as admirable not shameful.  So now mark your answer as accepted, to help others that may have the same question.