# What is best way to search from optional parameter to SQL query in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-like, optional-parameters

When it comes to search record with optional parameter in SQL stored procedure, out of these two queries. Both return the same results. Considering performance, which one will you use and why?

I have a stored procedure which has multiple search parameters and will be searching in multiple tables, with joins from a huge record set.

```
DECLARE @EventName VARCHAR(100)
--SET @EventName = ''
--SET @EventName = NULL
SET @EventName = 'Coffee in Coffee Bean'

-- Query - 1
SELECT * 
FROM EventDetails
WHERE 
    1 = CASE 
           WHEN @EventName IS NULL OR @EventName = '' THEN 1 
           WHEN EventName LIKE '%'+ @EventName +'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END

-- Query - 2
SELECT * 
FROM EventDetails
WHERE 
    EventName LIKE '%' + CASE 
                            WHEN LEN(LTRIM(@EventName)) > 0 
                               THEN @EventName 
                               ELSE EventName 
                         END + '%'
```

Comment: Your best bet for performance with optional parameters (and I know it might be ugly) is Dynamic SQL. You can omit entire filters with it.

Comment: @EzLo: I know but that would be riskest sql which can create like sql injections (if anyone enter query in parameter value) would give entire table output.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Comment: @marc_s: problem is records are not in system yet, its being created it will take 6 months or so... yet cant run horses :) just judging them before :)

Comment: Well, then **generate** a similar set, and run  your queries against that, and see for yourself ....

Comment: There are lots of tools and programming libraries out there that will allow you to easily create a realistic set of test data, so you can run your queries against it and make your measurements

Comment: Thank you @marc_s. When I ran this query against table of millions records, 1st query is way faster than 2nd query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by writing a single query

```
SELECT * 
FROM EventDetails
WHERE ((@EventName IS NULL OR @EventName) OR (EventName LIKE '%'+ @EventName +'%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

My money is on this:

```
IF ISNULL(@EventName), '') = ''
  SELECT * FROM EventDetails
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM EventDetails WHERE EventName = '%' + @EventName + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't consider dynamic SQL, then try to use as less functions and data tampering as possible. The most common approach for this would be something like the following:

```
DECLARE @OptionalFilter1 INT
DECLARE @OptionalFilter2 VARCHAR(100)
-- ...
DECLARE @OptionalFilterN BIT

SELECT
    YourColumns
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    (@OptionalFilter1 IS NULL OR @OptionalFilter1 = T.Filter1Column) AND
    (@OptionalFilter2 IS NULL OR @OptionalFilter2 = T.Filter2Column) AND
    -- ...
    (@OptionalFilterN IS NULL OR @OptionalFilterN = T.FilterNColumn)
```

For your example would be:

```
DECLARE @EventName VARCHAR(100) = 'Coffee in Coffee Bean'

SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    EventDetails AS E
WHERE
    (@EventName IS NULL OR E.Event LIKE '%' + @EventName + '%')
```

If this is gonna end in a procedure, consider using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the query with many filters and/or assigning the stored procedure parameters to new local scope variables to prevent parameter sniffing. You can read about parameter sniffing problem (with an example similar to yours) [in this post](https://hackernoon.com/why-parameter-sniffing-hurts-your-sql-query-performance-d73c0da71fbc).

Comment: This is great answer between all queries, your answer gives fastest result. Thank you! @EzLo