# MySQL: Making stored procedure multiple parameters optional

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure with multiple input optional parameters. If parameters for at least one of the fields are given, I still want some result meeting the criteria.

Here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblinquiries` (
  `UID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReviewDate` date NOT NULL,
  `InquiryId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `AuditStatus` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssignedTo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Result` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ResultCategories` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AuditBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Remarks` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `EndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (InquiryId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here is a sample data set:

```
INSERT INTO `tblinquiries` (`UID`, `ReviewDate`, `InquiryId`, `AuditStatus`, `AssignedTo`, `Result`, `ResultCategories`, `AuditBy`, `Remarks`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`) VALUES
('user1', '2018-07-07', '109933881', 'Assigned', 'auditor1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-07-15 08:03:47', NULL),
('user2', '2018-07-07', '109933885', 'Assigned', 'auditor2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2018-07-15 08:04:13', NULL),
('user3', '2018-07-07', '109933909', 'Complete', 'auditor3', 1, auditor3, NULL, NULL, '2018-07-15 08:06:42', '2018-07-15 08:10:42'),
('user4', '2018-07-08', '109933916', 'Check', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('user5', '2018-07-08', '109933917', 'Check', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('user6', '2018-07-08', '8790804', 'Complete', 'auditor1', 1, NULL, 'auditor1', NULL, '2018-07-14 21:19:25', '2018-07-14 21:21:29');
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `spInquiries`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInquiries` (IN `pReviewStartDate` DATE, IN `pReviewEndDate` DATE, IN `pAuditStartDate` DATE, IN `pAuditEndDate` DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tblinquiries
  WHERE
  (ReviewDate BETWEEN pReviewStartDate AND pReviewEndDate)
  AND (DATE(EndTime) BETWEEN pAuditStartDate AND pAuditEndDate);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

After researching a lot, I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697671/stored-procedure-with-optional-where-parameters) that has some similarity. But I don't how I can make 2 parameters (e.g - pAuditStartDate, pAuditEndDate) null for the WHERE clause.

I have added an SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df2da9/1).

I want some result for both the command:

```
CALL spInquiries('', '', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');
CALL spInquiries('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31', '', '');
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL casts automatically the `date` type from strings so you can use string instead of `date` parameters. BTW the empty date (`''`) is not valid as MySQL date value.

After that you can change the value, if the comparison is from lower date then use `'1900-01-01'` as default and `now()` for higher range.

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists `spInquiries`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInquiries` (IN `pReviewStartDate` varchar(30), IN `pReviewEndDate` varchar(30),
                              IN `pAuditStartDate` varchar(30), IN `pAuditEndDate` varchar(30))
BEGIN

  -- sanitize the date ranges
  if pReviewStartDate = '' then 
    set pReviewStartDate = '1900-01-01';
  end if;
  if pAuditStartDate = '' then 
    set pAuditStartDate = '1900-01-01';
  end if;

  if pReviewEndDate = '' then 
    set pReviewEndDate = now();
  end if;

  if pAuditEndDate = '' then 
    set pAuditEndDate = now();
  end if;

  -- now you can run the query without problems

  SELECT * FROM tblinquiries
   WHERE
    (ReviewDate BETWEEN pReviewStartDate AND pReviewEndDate)
     AND (DATE(EndTime) BETWEEN pAuditStartDate AND pAuditEndDate);
END$$
```

Results:

```
mysql> CALL spInquiries('', '', '2018-07-01', '2018-07-31');
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UID   | ReviewDate | InquiryId | AuditStatus | AssignedTo | Result | ResultCategories | AuditBy  | Remarks | StartTime           | EndTime             |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user3 | 2018-07-07 | 109933909 | Complete    | auditor3   |      1 |                0 | NULL     | NULL    | 2018-07-15 08:06:42 | 2018-07-15 08:10:42 |
| user6 | 2018-07-08 | 8790804   | Complete    | auditor1   |      1 |             NULL | auditor1 | NULL    | 2018-07-14 21:19:25 | 2018-07-14 21:21:29 |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+


mysql> CALL spInquiries('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31', '', '');
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UID   | ReviewDate | InquiryId | AuditStatus | AssignedTo | Result | ResultCategories | AuditBy  | Remarks | StartTime           | EndTime             |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user3 | 2018-07-07 | 109933909 | Complete    | auditor3   |      1 |                0 | NULL     | NULL    | 2018-07-15 08:06:42 | 2018-07-15 08:10:42 |
| user6 | 2018-07-08 | 8790804   | Complete    | auditor1   |      1 |             NULL | auditor1 | NULL    | 2018-07-14 21:19:25 | 2018-07-14 21:21:29 |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------+----------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Update:**

I change the stored procedure to meet the new paramter

```
DELIMITER $$
drop procedure if exists `spInquiries`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `spInquiries` (IN `pReviewStartDate` varchar(30), IN `pReviewEndDate` varchar(30),
                                IN `pAuditStartDate` varchar(30), IN `pAuditEndDate` varchar(30), 
                                pInquiryId VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

  if pReviewStartDate = '' then 
    set @pReviewStartDate = '1900-01-01';
  else
    set @pReviewStartDate = pReviewStartDate;
  end if;
  if pAuditStartDate = '' then 
    set @pAuditStartDate = '1900-01-01';
  else
    set @pAuditStartDate = pAuditStartDate;
  end if;

  if pReviewEndDate = '' then 
    set @pReviewEndDate = now();
  else
    set @pReviewEndDate = pReviewEndDate;
  end if;

  if pAuditEndDate = '' then 
    set @pAuditEndDate = now();
  else
    set @pAuditEndDate = pAuditEndDate;
  end if;

  set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblinquiries WHERE 
            (ReviewDate BETWEEN ? AND ?)
             AND (DATE(EndTime) BETWEEN ? AND ?) ';

  if pInquiryId = '' then
    set @sql = concat(@sql,"AND InquiryId IS NULL");
  else
    set @sql = concat(@sql,"AND InquiryId =  '", pInquiryId,"'");
  end if; 

  PREPARE myquery FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE myquery using @pReviewStartDate,@pReviewEndDate,@pAuditStartDate,@pAuditEndDate;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @ Ivan It worked but I wanted to add another parameter **IN `pInquiryId` varchar(30)** and added like this.

**SELECT * FROM tblinquiries
   WHERE
    (ReviewDate BETWEEN pReviewStartDate AND pReviewEndDate)
     AND (DATE(EndTime) BETWEEN pAuditStartDate AND pAuditEndDate) AND (pInquiryId IS NULL OR InquiryId = pInquiryId);**

It gives an error for the command CALL spInquiries('2018-07-01', '2018-07-31', '', '', '');

What is wrong?

Comment: So, do you want to select all records with InquiryId = NULL when pInquiryId = '' ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. How do I do that?

Comment: I added some changes to stored procedure, in this case the NULL comparison is not trivial.